# Redis evict keys before memory is full

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I am using Redis as a simple key-value store. I am actually using a Heroku plugin (Redis Cloud), but i don't think that matter for that question. Ok, the available memory for Redis is 1GB and the eviction policy is set to `allkeys lru`. I do not set a ttl when storing the data. My understanding would be that the data stays in Redis until the memory is full. Then the last recently used data gets evicted. But that is not what happens. Redis uses constantly around 3MB of the memory and removes data very soon.

Am I understanding something wrong here? Why does Redis not keep the data in memory?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Are you sure the available memory for Redis (i.e. the maxmemory parameter) is 1 GB and not 1 MB?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. The limit is 1GB, used is ~3MB or 0.3%. That's at least what the management console says...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Redis itself is not the problem. One of the Django plugins that I am using (django-redis-cache, redis-py) sets a default TTL of 300 seconds.